# Trigger workflow when branch created

Tags: github, github-actions

I am having two workflows - one is get triggered when new branch is created and second one is get triggered on push event.

The problem is whenever new branch is created these two workflows getting triggered together.
**Is there any way to control multiple workflow triggers in github.**

Below is  the yaml

workflow 1:

```
name: Feature Branch WorkFlow
on:
    push:
      branches-ignore:
        - main
```

workflow 2:

```
name: Create App Service Slot
on:
 create:
```

actually I am trying to create a app service slot in azure whenever a new branch is created from main branch in github.
Second workflow should only run when new code push happen - This will build and deploy the app on Azure app service slot.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you manage the trigger for both workflows i.e

**workflow 1:** Runs only on push events to branches expect for main branch

```
name: Feature Branch WorkFlow
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - '**'
    # skip triggering for pushes to the main branch
    if: "!startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/heads/main')"

jobs:
  build:
```

**workflow 2:** create a app service slot in azure whenever a new branch is created from main branch in github.

```
name: Create App Service Slot
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - '**'
    if: |
      # trigger for new branches created from main branch
      test ${{ github.event_name }} = 'push' &&
      test ${{ github.ref_type }} = 'branch' &&
      test ${{ github.head_ref }} != 'main'

jobs:
  build:
```

Comment: I have tried it but both the workflows are getting triggered.